# Query structure to fetch time frames by date

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Let's say I have a booking table described as followed :

```
id: INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
start_at: DATE
end_at: DATE
```

Now, let's say I have around 5 millions records in this table, equally distributed between 2020 and 2025.

The naïve query to fetch ongoing bookings at a certain date would be:

```
SELECT count(b.id) 
from booking b 
where b.start_at <= '2022-04-21' 
and b.end_at >= '2022-04-21'
```

After adding indices on start_at and end_at, the query is really fast on dates closed to the end of 2025 and start of 2020 because optimizer select one of the index that filter out most of the data.

However, when I try to fetch bookings that occured in the middle of 2022, the query become very slow, on my benchmark, the query run for more close to 10 seconds.

I thought that a more appropriate way would be to have two distinct query that I will intersect to get the most out of my indices.

I added two indices (id, start_at) and (id, end_at) and tried an inner join on the table itself

```
SELECT count(b.id) 
from booking b
    INNER JOIN booking b2 ON b.id = b2.id and b2.start_at < '2022-04-21'
    INNER JOIN booking b3 ON b.id = b3.id and b3.end_at > '2022-04-21'
```

The query became slower by a few but my indices were not used at all.

If I forced the usage of my indices this way

```
SELECT count(b.id) 
from booking b
    INNER JOIN booking b2 force index(booking_id_start_IDX) ON b.id = b2.id 
            and b2.start_at < '2023-04-21'
    INNER JOIN booking b3 force index(booking_id_end_IDX) ON b.id = b3.id 
            and b3.end_at > '2023-04-21';
```

Query is divided by a half running in 4 seconds but it's still not acceptable.

What is the right pattern to query on a range ?